# One core app with multiple servlets

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I created a webapp (written in Eclipse, running in Tomcat) that was one Servlet, which upon it's initialization created a Runnable object.  The Runnable object does a load of stuff and stores some data in memory, the servlet exists only to present to users the latest pieces of data in the object (there's no DB, we only care about the current data).

The thing is, I now want to have another Servlet access the same data and presenting it to the user in a different way, which means the model of Servlet creating Runnable object is no longer feasible.

So, my question is this:  How can I create an application that has one main class doing all the work, and a bunch of Servlets talking to it to get data?

As a work-around which I don't particularly like I've just made the doGet() method parse the request string and send a different response based on its contents, but I'd rather do it with separate Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Runnable object during `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` method and set it to the `ServletContext` as an attribute using `ServletContext.setAttribute()`.

And, both the servlet's can get the Runabble object from the `ServletContext.getAttribute()` and present the data.

Comment: Don't forget that the object you place in the ServletContext (aka "application scope") either must be thread-safe or must be accessed in a thread-safe way (e.g. using a synchronized block on the object itself). This should have been the case all along (because the servlet itself had some state), but its worth mentioning.